# Tag hgroup está inutilizada?

Tags: html5

Estava vendo algumas vídeo-aulas sobre HTML5 e me deparei com a tag **hgroup** que serve para agrupar `h1`,`h2`..., lendo [isso](http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/) hoje de manhã vi que ela foi removida do HTML5. Isso confere? não é mais necessário estudar ela?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Após [muita discussão](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Mar/0026.html) o elemento **`<hgroup>`** foi [removido](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html) da HTML5.

Comment: Muito obrigado. `off-topic` peraí, você é o verdadeiro Maujor?

Comment: Sim sou o verdadeiro [Maujor](http://maujor.com) ao vivo e à cores! 
Não respondo dúvidas em chat ou por email, mas costumo aparecer em listas e fóruns.

Comment: Pergunto isso, pois aprendi praticamente tudo de CSS em seu site! \o

Comment: Caraca, respondido pelo próprio maujor!!

Comment: Eu merecia uma medalha, não? ahahhaha :D

Comment: Maujor, caso você não tenha sido notificado na outra resposta (excluída), vou repetir aqui. Sou leitor do seu site há muitos anos, e é um prazer te ver aqui no Stack Overflow em Português! Seja bem-vindo, suas colaborações certamente agregarão um conteúdo valioso!

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela recepção.

Comment: de nada, qualquer duvida sobre css pode me perguntar hahahaha

Comment: Não seria interessante transcrever e traduzir as motivações que levaram a etiqueta a ser removida aqui para a resposta ? Assim ajudava a quem passasse por esta resposta a ficar mais elucidado do porquê de já não existir.

Comment: O elemento (não é uma etiqueta e sim um elemento da marcação HTML) foi removido por ser, na prática, de valor semântico nulo.
Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup

Answer (score 2):

***Como o amigo @Maujor comentou, a tag `<hgroup>` está obsoleta https://caniuse.com/#search=hgroup***

---

Mas como complemento gostaria de deixar uma solução mais semântica e atualizada usando a tag `<header>`.

Segundo a **W3C:**

> A `header` element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an `h1–h6` element), but this is not required. The header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos.

Traduzindo:

*"Um elemento `header` deve conter geralmente o cabeçalho da seção (um elemento `h1 – h6`), mas isso não é necessário. O elemento `header` também pode ser usado para agrupar o índice de uma seção, um formulário de pesquisa ou qualquer logotipo relevante."*

Fonte: https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/sections.html#the-header-element

Exemplo básico:

```html
<header>
 <h1>Welcome to...</h1>
 <h2>StackOverflow!</h2>
</header>
```