# porque hgrup foi descontinuado? algum substituto no local?

Tags: html5

```
<header id="cabecario">
    <hgroup>
<h1>Cristiano Rodrigues&copy;</h1>
<h2>Bem vindo ao meu mundo!!!</h2>
    </hgroup>

    <img src="_imagens/glass-oculos-preto-peq.png">
        <h4>Administrador e propietario do site</h4>


<nav><!--Titulado para menu -->
    <h1>Menu Principal</h1>
    <ul tapy ="circle">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="atualidade.html">Atualidades</a></li>
        <li>Projeto</li>
        <li>Cursos</li>
        <li>Artigo Pudricados<ol><em>Bibliotecas</em></ol></li>
        <li>Conhecimentos<ol><em>Ferramentas</em></ol><ol><em>Gadget</em></ol></li>
        <li>Vamos conversar?&clubs;</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse assunto já foi discutido em outra questão: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27077/tag-hgroup-est%c3%a1-inutilizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27077/tag-hgroup-est%C3%A1-inutilizada)

Sobre como substituir, não há outra tag definida para a mesma função semântica do `hgroup`, mas é possível usar `CSS` combinado com outras tags para chegar a um resultado satisfatório, veja esses exemplos e de como usar subtítulos:

[w3c.github.io - subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines](http://w3c.github.io/html/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines)

[www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/html5-hgroup-is-dead-what-you-need-to-know/](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/html5-hgroup-is-dead-what-you-need-to-know/)

Só lembrando que, dependendo da combinação de tags, ou ainda se usar outros elementos diferentes das tags de títulos (`H1`, `H2`, etc) pode mudar a forma como os indexadores de busca tratam sua página (SEO). Leia mais aqui: [www.seomaster.com.br/blog/como-usar-as-heading-tags](http://www.seomaster.com.br/blog/como-usar-as-heading-tags)

Comment: Obriga, ótimas referencias!!!!