# qual outra tag pode ser utilizada para substituir o hgoup?

Tags: html5

estou estudando html5 e fiquei sabendo que a tag hgroup não está mais sendo utilizada.queria saber qual outra tag pode ser usada para substituir??

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Tag hgroup está inutilizada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27077/tag-hgroup-est%c3%a1-inutilizada)

Comment: sim,parece que pega em alguns poucos navegadores.

Comment: Não acho duplicata, uma pergunta se a tag foi removida a outra pergunta sobre uma substituta

Comment: Tb não acho repetida. Uma pergunta se foi descontinuada e a outra pergunta por qual deve ser substituída, já que na pergunta antiga não fazem menção a isso... Mas atente, que mesmo a tag antiga hgroup funcionando em alguns navegadores ela pode deixar de funcionar a qualquer nova atualização do browser. Além disso, muito provavelmente não vai ser um HTML válido e provavelmente vai dar erro no validador da W3C https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diferente da resposta citada como duplicada, na qual apenas comprova que a ta `<hgroup>` foi descontinuada. [Tag hgroup está inutilizada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27077/tag-hgroup-est%C3%A1-inutilizada)

Na atualidade, de acordo com a documentação da Mozilla vc pode usar a tag `<header>` para agrupar seus títulos: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header#Usage_notes

> The `<header>` element is not sectioning content and therefore does not
>   introduce a new section in the outline. That said, a `<header>` element
>   is intended to usually contain the surrounding section's heading (an
>   `h1–h6` element), but this is not required.

Tradução:

*"O elemento `<header>` não é um conteúdo de seccionamento e, portanto, não introduz uma nova seção no esquema. Dito isso, um elemento `<header>` deve conter o título da seção circundante (um elemento `h1 – h6`), mas isso não é necessário."*

Ex:

```
<header>
    <h1>Meu título principal</h1>
    <h2>Meu subtítulo</h2>
</header>
```

Dessa forma vc mantem a semântica da estrutura e consegue agrupar seus títulos

Comment: entendi,valeu :)

Comment: @impossivel-não nada é impossível :D! Quanto tiver um tempo pesquise sobre tag semânticas, vai te ajudar muito com esse tipo de coisa. Boa sorte ai abs!

Comment: de boa .........

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer apenas agrupar os títulos,  então use `<div>`, não conheço nenhuma outra tag que tenha um valor semântico melhor para esse caso (já que `hgroup` foi removida)

Comment: tag `<header>` :)

Comment: ok ,valeu ai :)