# Como inserir uma imagem via CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

Segue meu códido HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>web page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type='text/css' href="css/estilo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="principal">
<section id="corpo">
<header>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>#desafio100videos &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Faltam 13 videos</h1>

        <ul id="imagens">
            <li id="01"></li>
            <li id="02"></li>
            <li id="03"></li>
            <li id="04"></li> 
            <li id="05"></li>
            <li id="06"></li>
        </ul>

    </hgroup>
</header>
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>


Segue meu código CSS:
@charset "UTF-8";

section#corpo {
    width: 1300px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: Blippo, fantasy;
}


ul#album-fotos {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: nome;
}

ul#imagens li{
    float: left;
    width: 225px;
    height: 165px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 5px, solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0,.4);
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in;
}

ul#imagens li span{
    opacity: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    font-size: 9pt;
    line-height: 370px;
    padding: 5px;
}


ul#imagens li#01{
    background-image: url('../img/_text.png');
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 400px 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

ul#imagens li#01:hover{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

Comment: Bruno como o @Maujor comentou abaixo a tab `<hgroup>` não deve ser mais usada, pois está obsoleta, leia a respeito aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/331928/qual-outra-tag-pode-ser-utilizada-para-substituir-o-hgoup

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Seu problema é que vc colocou um `ID` como número! Não se deve usar numerais como nome de `ID`

A [documentação do HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) não da muitos detalhes do que pode ou não ser usado como valor para o ID, mas a documentação do HTML4 é mais restritiva, e pode ser que o motor do browser leve essa regra em consideração.

> `ID` and `NAME` tokens **must begin with a letter** (`[A-Za-z]`) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits (`[0-9]`), hyphens ("`-`"), underscores ("`_`"), colons ("`:`"), and periods ("`.`").

Em resumo ID e nomes deve começar com letras *(inclusive o HTML e CSS são sencíveis a Caixa Alta!)* `*N*ome` é diferente de `nome`

*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Veja no exemplo abaixo. A div que o `ID` que está com letras pega o estilo, já a que tem `ID` com número não pega o estilo.

```
div#nome <!-- OK -->

div#01 <!-- ERRO -->

div#texto01 <!-- OK -->
```

**OBS** No entanto vc pode colocar números no `ID`, desde que não seja o primeiro caractere!

**Repare que a `div` com o `2` não renderizou o CSS pq o `ID` começa com um numeral!**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div#nome {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
}
div#01 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
}
div#texto01 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
}
html {color:red}
```

```html
<div id="nome">1</div>
<div id="01">2</div>
<div id="texto01">3</div>
```

Comment: @BrunoSuarez - O elemento `hgroup` foi retirado da HTM5 e seu uso deve ser evitado. 
A Especificação prevê algumas [alternativas de marcação para substituir esse elemento](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements)

Comment: @Maujor acho que vc queria comentar na verdade na pergunta do Bruno né. Como eu montei esse modelo da minha resposta na mão sem usar o código que o Bruno postou acabou que eu não notei que ele tinha usado a tag `<hgroup>` que como vc mencionou está em desuso. E até por coincidência eu já tinha incluído essa alternativa do link que vc postou na mesma pergunta que vc tb já tinha respondido sobre `hgroup` aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/331928/qual-outra-tag-pode-ser-utilizada-para-substituir-o-hgoup/331951#331951

Comment: Perfeito! Minhas desculpas, o comentário realmente era na pergunta do Bruno.

Comment: @Maujor sem problemas meu caro, eu tb me equivoquei rss, o link que eu queria falar na verdade é esse aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27077/tag-hgroup-est%C3%A1-inutilizada/ . Tem uns dias que eu inclui lá uma resposta falando de uma possível alternativa para a tag `hgroup` usando a tag `header`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal.

Comment: @BrunoSuarez que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone **`✔`** abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita mesmo já tendo sido resolvido.